# Mapview swift add multiple markers

Tags: ios, swift3

```
for result in swiftyData.arrayValue {
                        let classId = result[0].stringValue
                        let className = result[1].stringValue
                        let longitude = result[2].doubleValue
                        let latitude = result[3].doubleValue
                        let newClass = NearestClasses()
                        newClass.classId = classId
                        newClass.className = className
                        newClass.longitude = longitude
                        newClass.latitude = latitude
                        nearestClasses?.append(newClass)

                        let locationSec = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(CLLocationDegrees(latitude), CLLocationDegrees(longitude))
                        dropPin.coordinate = newYorkLocation                           
                        dropPin.title =  className
                        self.mapeView.addAnnotation(dropPin)*/                            
                        let dropPin =  MKPointAnnotation()
                        dropPin.coordinate = locationSec                            
                        dropPin.title =  className                            
                        self.mapeView.addAnnotation(dropPin)   
                    }
```

If its one loop, this function works perfectly in swift 3. But if its multiple loop, no markers are showing on the map. Thank you

Comment: you're using `dropPin` before you declare it - I'm not sure how this will compile at all

Comment: your code is buggy please provide exact code that is working because your given code will not work as droppin is not init before using.

Answer (score 2):

**In Swift 3**

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    var latitude:Double!
    var longitude:Double!
    var locationManager =  CLLocationManager()
    var green:Bool = false
    var red:Bool = false
    var yellow:Bool = false
    var blue:Bool = false
    var darkBlue:Bool = false
    var liteGreen:Bool = false


  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled())
        {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            if ((UIDevice.current.systemVersion as NSString).floatValue >= 8)
            {
                locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            }

            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
        else
        {
            #if debug
                println("Location services are not enabled");
            #endif
        }
 addAnnotationPoint()
    }
```

**Add Annotation Function**

```
 func addAnnotationPoint()
    {

                       for data in yourArray
                {

                    let point = MKPointAnnotation()

                    let pointlatitude = Double(data.latitude!)!
                    let pointlongitude = Double(data.longitude!)!
                    point.title = data.event_name

                    point.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(pointlatitude ,pointlongitude)
                    //print(point.coordinate)
                    mapView.addAnnotation(point)


                }
                let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.075, 0.075)
                let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude), span: span)
                mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        }
```

**Annotation View Method**

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        // Don't want to show a custom image if the annotation is the user's location.
        guard !(annotation is MKUserLocation) else {
            return nil
        }

        // Better to make this class property
        let annotationIdentifier = "AnnotationIdentifier"

        var annotationView: MKAnnotationView?
        if let dequeuedAnnotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: annotationIdentifier) {
            annotationView = dequeuedAnnotationView
            annotationView?.annotation = annotation
        }
        else {
            annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)
            annotationView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
        }

        if let annotationView = annotationView {

           // annotationView.canShowCallout = true

                if blue == true
                {
                    blue = false
                    green = true
                    yellow = false
                    red = false
                    darkBlue = false
                    liteGreen = false

                    annotationView.image =  imageLiteral(resourceName: "Bluepin")

                }
                else if green == true
                {
                    blue = false
                    green = false
                    darkBlue = false
                    liteGreen = false
                    yellow = true
                    red = false
                    annotationView.image =  imageLiteral(resourceName: "Greenpin")

                }
                else if yellow == true
                {
                    blue = false
                    green = false
                    yellow = false
                    darkBlue = false
                    liteGreen = false
                    red = true
                    annotationView.image =  imageLiteral(resourceName: "Yellopin")

                }
                else if red == true
                {
                    blue = false
                    green = false
                    yellow = false
                    darkBlue = true
                    liteGreen = false
                    red = false
                    annotationView.image =  imageLiteral(resourceName: "Redpin")

            }
                else if darkBlue == true
                {
                    blue = false
                    green = false
                    yellow = false
                    darkBlue = false
                    liteGreen = true
                    red = false
                    annotationView.image =  imageLiteral(resourceName: "DarkBlue")

                }
                else if liteGreen == true
                {
                    blue = true
                    green = false
                    yellow = false
                    darkBlue = false
                    liteGreen = false
                    red = false
                    annotationView.image =  imageLiteral(resourceName: "LiteGreen")

                }
            else
                {
                    blue = true
                    green = false
                    yellow = false
                    red = false
                    annotationView.image =  imageLiteral(resourceName: "Pinkpin")
            }


        }

        return annotationView
    }
```